# Bootstrap datetimepicker / Moments.js to confirm user's age

Tags: jquery, datepicker, momentjs

I am needing away to check a person's age when they sign up. We want to only allow users over the age of 13.

I am wondering how to do this, as I don't get the documentation. I am using jQuery latest edition.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats

Comment: How did you get on with the seemingly useful below, RussellHarrower? It seems unusual that it was entirely unreplied to.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use `moment.diff()` to get a precise measure in milliseconds between two times, that's not what you want for an age check. A person is at least 13 if they were born on or before today's date 13 years ago.

```
var isOldEnough = function(birthdate) {
    var now = moment();
    var birth = moment(birthdate);
    var birthDay   = birth.format('DD');
    var birthMonth = birth.format('MM');
    var birthYear  = birth.format('YYYY');
    var thisDay    = now.format('DD');
    var thisMonth  = now.format('MM');
    var thisYear   = now.format('YYYY');

    //a person is at least 13 if they were born on or before today's date 13 years ago
    if(thisYear - birthYear >= 13 && thisMonth >= birthMonth && thisDay >= birthDay) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Given that I answered your question on 8/16/2015, I wanted to check dates surrounding today but 13 years ago, so I checked today, yesterday, and tomorrow of 2002. Only tomorrow should return false and the method above handles this correctly.

```
var a = '8/15/2002';
var b = '8/16/2002';
var c = '8/17/2002';

isOldEnough(a); //yes
isOldEnough(b); //yes
isOldEnough(c); //no
```

Of course, the above is based on time of writing.